# Bootstrap dropdown-menu display error left

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown-menu on my dropdown btn is diplaying awkwardly to the left (see image).  How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a map!
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dust II</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mirage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inferno</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">More coming soon!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your coding working perfectly fine I don't know where is the error come from, can you give full coding

html and css

You can check from here http://www.bootply.com/v0PX9nmUro

I will update my answer after i see yours coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to change your

```
<ul class="`enter code here`dropdown-menu">
```

to

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```